# Sequence of events to fix and push git merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge

I just merged `develop` into my feature branch (via `git merge develop`) and got about 20 merge conflicts. Sure enough when I do a `git status` I see output like:

```
        new file:   src/test/resources/com/example/mapper/test/TestAccountMapper.xml
        new file:   src/test/resources/vc-import-data/DATAFILE-unwrapped.xml
        new file:   src/test/resources/vc-import-data/DATAFILE.xml

Unmerged paths:
(use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both added:      src/main/java/com/example/bean/Account.java
        both added:      src/main/java/com/example/bean/Address.java
        both added:      src/main/java/com/example/bean/Customer.java
        both added:      src/main/java/com/example/mapper/AccountMapper.java
        both added:      src/main/java/com/example/mapper/CountryMapper.java
        both added:      src/main/resources/com/example/mapper/AccountMapper.xml
        both added:      src/main/resources/com/example/mapper/AddressMapper.xml
        both added:      src/main/resources/com/example/mapper/CustomerMapper.xml
        both modified:   src/main/resources/endpoints.properties
        both added:      src/test/java/com/example/mapper/AccountMapperTest.java
        both added:      src/test/java/com/example/mapper/CustomerMapperTest.java
        both modified:   src/test/resources/test-endpoints.properties
```

I have now gone through each conflicted file and merged everything by hand. Can I just do a `git add . && git commit -m "Resolved merge conflicts" && git push`? Or do I need to do anything else (and if so, in what order)?

Comment: `git add .` followed by `git merge --continue` should work with the latest git.

Comment: *Can I just do ...*  Yes, precisely that. Note that `git merge --continue` just runs `git commit` (after making sure you're finishing up a merge); it's not super-new, it has been around for a while, and it's kind of nicer than an explicit `git commit` since it double checks that you know what you're doing. But you can definitely run `git commit` directly, and in the bad old days, you *had* to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this
git add --all,
git commit -m "comments"and then
git push origin feature